# Can I "prime the pump" for Symantec Endpoint Protection Liveupdate?

Tags: symantec-endpoint-protection

I have a secure network firewalled from the Internet.  I have about 25 linux machines running Symantec Endpoint Protection on this network, connected by a small (2Mb/s) link to my company's "central" network that includes a Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager.

On a day-to-day basis, we use Symantec LiveUpdate to update the virus definitions on those machines.  This works well; it takes about 4 minutes per machine.

However, when a new version of SEP is released, or when I create/install a new machine, the machine(s) will contact my SEP Mgr and download a fresh full set of virus definitions.  This takes about 25 minutes, and I would rather it didn't.

So I'm trying to find out if there is a file or a set of files that I can download once to a machine on my private network, and have my new machines download the full virus definitions from there, and then begin using the SEP Mgr for the daily updates.

The only thing I have found so far is the Symantec "Intelligent Update" https://www.symantec.com/security_response/definitions/download/detail.jsp?gid=sep .  Intelligent Update will let me store the full virus definition locally, but it is not compatible with LiveUpdate.  That is, you cannot follow an Intelligent Update with a LiveUpdate.  You can only follow Intelligent Update with another (full) Intelligent Update, or replace it completely with a fresh full LiveUpdate.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: mcafee got that at 75% of your feature, they called that feature *superdat* file. (like shown [there](http://www.mcafee.com/apps/downloads/security-updates/security-updates.aspx) ), so a universal file to update to the latest version. never seen that feature for symantec...